# Error: ! Package utf8x Error: MalformedUTF-8sequence. using \include{} function

Tags: include, spanish, multiple-files

I'm writing my thesis in spanish on latex and I'm using the `\include{}` function to bring other .tex files to my master.tex (main file).

My encoding looks something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
.
.
\begin{document}
some text here...
\tableofcontents
\include{chapter1}
.
.
\end{document}
```

The thing is that the master.tex file writes perfectly spanish accents. But, when I try to include a chapter, it comes out with this error (! Package utf8x Error: MalformedUTF-8sequence.) And I checked it out and, for example it comes when I do:

```
This is chapter1.tex:
\chapter{Justificación del tema}
.
.
(in master.tex file: \include{chapter1}
```

It comes with the error when I do the ó, but If I write "Justificacion" (with no " ´ " on top of the "o", everythings fine.

Does anybody know how can I get this fixed? Do I have to put something on top of the `chapter1.tex` file?

To know:
- I'm using TexMAKER on Windows 7.

I'd be very grateful if someone could help me!
Thank you and greetings from Chile!

Comment: You can't get an error linked to `utf8x` if you use the `utf8` option. However, this might mean the file is not UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Probably your chapter1.tex file is not utf8, despite what you declare in `inputenc`. If you are on a linux machine, try `file chapter1.tex` from command line to find out the encoding of that file.

Comment: @JorgeV For Windows there is a good (and free) editor called Notepad++, which has extensive support for converting/saving different encodings.

Comment: @JLDiaz, I just tried using Notepad++ for changing the encoding, but it says that actually the file is in utf8. Got any other idea? Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

If you are having the same problem I had, you just have to put the following code into the .tex files that are going to be included in your master file:

```
%!TEX root = master.tex
```

Say you are writing an introduction, you create the introduction.tex file and you include it in master.tex with `\include{introduction.tex}`. The above code should be **at the top of `introduction.tex`.**

(The `master.tex` file is your main document.)